# Error using filesize() function

Tags: php

I'm writing an image uploader to go with my php gallery. I'm putting restrictions on the type of files the user can upload and the size of the file. I'm getting an error using the filesize() function. I've omitted the full path and replaced it just with path. This is the error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: uploaded in path/upload.php on line 19 Notice: Undefined index: uploaded in path/upload.php on line 54 Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.
```

When I ls in the photo directory the photo is uploaded and appears on my gallery page. Does anyone know why I'm getting this error and how to fix it? Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head><title>File Manager!</title></head>

<body>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
 Please choose a file: <input name="uploaded" type="file" /><br />
 <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
 </form>

</body>

</html>

<?php 


$targetDir = "/students/jmartz/public_html/130a/PhotoDir/";
$targetDir = $targetDir . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']); //Line 19
$goodFile=true;; 

//Line 22
$fileSize = filesize($targetDir);
if ($fileSize > 250000) 
{ 
    echo "Your file is too large.<br>"; 
    $goodFile = false;

}



$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$fileType = finfo_file($finfo, $targetDir);



$fileType = filetype($targetDir); 

//echo "File type: $fileType";
if ($fileType =="text/x-php") 
{ 
    echo "No PHP files<br>"; 
    $goodFile = false;
}    



if ($goodFile == false) 
{
    echo "Sorry your file was not uploaded"; 
}  
else 
{
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $targetDir)) //Line 54
    { 
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']). " has been uploaded"; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
    } 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You say the error is with filesize() but that is line 22 and the error is with line 19 and the `$_FILES` statement.

Use 'file' instead of 'uploaded'

```
$_FILES['file']['name']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this tutorial this may be helpful

**Reference**

http://blog.trofeosolution.com/index.php/blog/file-upload